# can the decimal precision of token contract be changed after launch to mainnet?

Tags: eosio.token

I'm having trouble getting my token to show up on the Meet.one wallet,  thought i had launched it with basic decimal precision of 4, but after testing with scatter can only send upto 2 decimal places.  Now meet.one is having trouble integrating it. Can this be change after the fact or have i hooped myself??

Comment: May be worth asking this in the official EOS Dev channel as well: https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg

Answer (score 0):

The data types within a table cannot be changed; assuming you based your token on the eosio.token contract, your precision is set in stone.

You could try to be fancy and ...

1. Add another table with the correct precision,
2. Pause the contract,
3. Move all the data over to the new table with the correct precision,
4. Delete all data in the old table,
5. Remove the old table,
6. Update the contract actions to reference the new table,
7. And then unpause the contract.

If you don't have to much data in the table yet, it will probably be easier to just redeploy.